# Difference between a UIViewController's view frame and navigationController.view.frame?

Tags: iphone

I have a UIViewController derived class that is part of a UINavigationController's view controller.

There's the view that's part of the UIViewController and there's also access to navigationController property.

So what's the difference between

```
self.navigationController.view.frame
```

vs

```
self.view.frame
```

in terms of the UIViewController class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`navigationController` is just a convenient property on `UIViewController` that gives you access to a view controller's containing navigation controller, should it have one. Since `UINavigationController` extends `UIViewController`, it, too, has a `view` property. See the documentation for [Getting Other Related View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW62) in `UIViewController`'s class reference for a list of other view controller references `UIViewController` can potentially have.

- `self.navigationController.view.frame` gives you the frame of the navigation controller's view
- `self.view.frame` gives you the frame of the view controller's view

A navigation controller's view frame is larger than any of its container view controllers' view frames because it includes the navigation bar and the status bar.

Hope this helps clear things up a bit!

Comment: Does it ever also include the tab bar height the Navigation controller is part of a TabBar?

Comment: No. The navigation controller has no awareness of the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the relationship of your view controllers, but in general `view.frame` returns a CGRect with coordinates (origin (x,y) and size(width,hieght)) relative to the views superview. So, if your navigationController is the parent view of your derived UIViewController, then calling 'self.view.frame' in that controller will return coordinates relative to the navigationController. Calling `self.navigationController.view.frame` will return its coordinates relative to its superview, whatever that might be.